# Equation to accelerate an object along a known curve until it reaches a target distance

Tags: physics, convergence-acceleration

This problem is deceptively simple, but it's been driving me mad:

I have a function, $f(x)$. At $f(0)$, it returns $0$ -- at $f(1)$, it returns $MaxSpeed$.

I have an object at rest and a target point 1 KM away. My goal is to move the object along a single dimension such that its speed always matches the output of that function. For example, when it's halfway there I'd expect $Speed = f(0.5)$ and when it hits the 1 KM goal, it would have $Speed = f(1) = MaxSpeed$.

---

My problem: $f(0)$ (initial spot for the object) gives a speed of $0$... so the object never moves. Giving the feedback loop a kick using something like `Speed = f(0.001)` does *eventually* do the proper thing, but it takes ages.

My gut says that I need to bring time into the problem somehow... but I'm fairly certain I can choose any 2 of "reasonable time," "reaches speed exactly at given distance," or "acceleration is determined by a function" and not all 3. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a constant acceleration $a = (x^2 - s^2)/(2d)$. If $x$ is larger, $a$ will be positive. If $s$ is larger, $a$ will be negative. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for.

Comment: @JohnBarber My main goal is to get an alpha that I can feed into my interpolation function -- with an alpha of 0 at the start of the block and an alpha of 1 at the end of the block.

I just changed the code to use your approach (having acceleration increase an alpha, which is used in the easing function to control speed). The train manages to reach max speed about halfway through, and stops about halfway short. Closer, but not perfect.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Are you trying to *find* an interpolation function, or do you *have* an interpolation function? And what do you mean by "interpolation function"? Do you mean a function that gives speed as a function of position?

Comment: Is "InterpolationFunc" any function that is positive and satisfies the condition that it takes the value "StartSpeed" when Alpha is 0 and "TargetSpeed" when Alpha is 1? In that case, this seems to be a question about numerically solving a differential equation.

Comment: @JohnBarber I _have_ an interpolation function -- a user-provided curve. The "InterpolationFunc" will be that curve, with the assumption that it returns "StartSpeed" when Alpha is 0 and "TargetSpeed" when Alpha is 1. All that's worked out, but the issue is in finding a suitable alpha for any arbitrary point between 0-1. My naïve approach was to just do `Alpha = TravelledDistance/TotalDistance` but that falls apart when you aren't moving. Maybe a piecewise function would work, but I wanted to make sure I'm not completely off my mark.

Comment: OK, I understand exactly what's happening now. You're basically solving a first order differential equation: Speed = Rate of change of position = Some function of position. But if that function always returns 0 when position = 0, it can never move, as you've seen. This type of problem can only be handled properly via a second-order ODE. You need to be getting an explicit acceleration. cont'd...

Comment: You need to have a function that, given current speed and position, and target speed and position, returns an acceleration. Then you'd be tracking the variables "position" and "speed," not just "position."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using a first-order ordinary differential equation (ODE) to describe a process that is fundamentally second-order in nature. (See: Newton's Second Law.) Instead of a function that gives speed/velocity, you need one that gives acceleration.

Let $x(t)$ represent position as a function of time $t$, and let $v(t)$ be velocity as a function of time. You're going to have a pair of coupled ODEs like this:
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &\;=\; v(t)\\[0.1in]
v'(t) &\;=\; a\bigl(x(t), v(t)\bigr)
\end{align*}
But what is the acceleration function $a(x,v)$? That's the tricky part. It's by no means trivial to allow an *arbitrary* function that does what you need it to. So I'm going to give you one special form for $a(x,v)$ that will work.

Say we start at initial position $x(0) = x_i$ with initial velocity $v(0) = v_i$. These are the *initial conditions* for your ODEs. Our goal is to arrive at a final position $x_f$ with some final velocity $v_f$. We don't care when we get there, we just want to have the specified velocity at that location. The rule $a(x,v)$ will follow is that given the current position $x$ and current velocity $v$, it will return that acceleration which, if held constant from that moment on, will deliver you to $x_f$ with velocity $v_f$. An introductory physics text will tell you that the function which accomplishes this is:
$$
a(x,v) \;=\; \frac{{v_f}^2 - v^2}{2(x_f - x)}
$$
This will - it turns out - give you a rather boring solution: The acceleration will remain constant, at its initial value, for the whole journey.

If you want a broader set of possible acceleration functions $a(x,v)$, you're going to have to apply some extra conditions. These may require more of the actual physics of whatever your object is (I think you said a train) in order to be consistent, so this may be a little bit more involved than it seemed at first.

ETA: If you're willing to accept some "dither" in the final speed, you can incorporate the force F(t) (the "thrust" of the engine) as a separate variable (along with some friction) with a rule whereby the force tries to adjust itself to change the speed of the train toward what it *thinks* the speed should currently be. This is more complicated, but gives cool results when I try it out in Mathematica. The following works very nicely, for instance:
\begin{align*}
x'(t) &\;=\; v(t)\\[0.1in]
v'(t) &\;=\; -\gamma\, v(t) \;+\; F(t)\\[0.1in]
F'(t) &\;=\; \beta\bigl(v_f \,-\, v(t)\bigr)
\end{align*}
Here $\gamma\geq 0$ is a friction/drag coefficient, and $\beta > 0$ is a sort of "train operator reaction time," i.e. it governs how fast the engineer realizes "Oh, I'm going faster/slower than I should be" and adjusts the engine thrust to compensate.